# python match data frame with a classification tree

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop, string-matching

Given the following data frames, one related to some transactional data and one related to some classification rules:

```
data = {'Transaction_description': ['sfdsjk fsjfdkj;f sfsdf RESTARANT', 'fsdk ;kjf;lskf;m gjkf NL111111111111 klkfdlo', 'golf kjnfksdn DE111111111112 fkdkk', 'jhfjd jhfj Jumbo jhf'], 'Amount': [-20, -21, -30, 10]} 
Transactions = pd.DataFrame(data)  

data = {
    'Priority': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
    'Type': ['IBAN', 'IBAN', 'Company', 'Company', 'Keyword','Keyword'],
    'Value': ['NL111111111111', 'DE111111111112', 'AMAZON', 'JUMBO','Restaurant','Golf'],
    'Priority': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'Description': ['', '', '', '','',''],
    'MappingCode': ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2','B1','B2']
    } 
Categorization = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to classify all the [Transaction_description] based on the [Priority] searching for the

```
(1) IBAN 
(2) Company 
(3) keyword.
```

Which is the most elegant why to get the following expected result:

```
data = {
    'Transaction_description': ['sfdsjk fsjfdkj;f sfsdf RESTARANT', 'fsdk ;kjf;lskf;m gjkf NL111111111111 klkfdlo', 'golf kjnfksdn DE111111111112 fkdkk', 'jhfjd jhfj Jumbo jhf'], 
    'Amount': [-20, -21, -30, 10],
    'MappingCode': ['B1','A1','A2','B2']
    } 
TransactionsClassified = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thanks and best regards,
Highbury

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a bit unstructured, that makes it somewhat harder.

- First of all, best to clean up your data a bit by removing some typo's and putting everything to lowercase.
- You can then create a column in your 'Transaction' dataframe which should contain the string you can merge on. You can do this by creating a list of possible strings, and then use `np.where()`. The order of the list will determine the order of the classification.
- Then merge your Categorization dataframe on this string

Your code could like look this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Data input
data = {'Transaction_description': ['sfdsjk fsjfdkj;f sfsdf RESTAURANT', 'fsdk ;kjf;lskf;m gjkf NL111111111111 klkfdlo', 'golf kjnfksdn DE111111111112 fkdkk', 'jhfjd jhfj Jumbo jhf'], 'Amount': [-20, -21, -30, 10]} 
Transactions = pd.DataFrame(data)  

data = {
    'Priority': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
    'Type': ['IBAN', 'IBAN', 'Company', 'Company', 'Keyword','Keyword'],
    'Value': ['NL111111111111', 'DE111111111112', 'AMAZON', 'JUMBO','Restaurant','Golf'],
    'Description': ['', '', '', '','',''],
    'MappingCode': ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2','B1','B2']
    } 
Categorization = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Make everything lowercase
Transactions["Transaction_description"] =  Transactions["Transaction_description"].str.lower()
Categorization["Value"] = Categorization["Value"].str.lower()

# Create the column you can merge on
keywordList = list(Categorization[Categorization["Type"] == "Keyword"]["Value"])
ibanList = list(Categorization[Categorization["Type"] == "IBAN"]["Value"])
companyList = list(Categorization[Categorization["Type"] == "Company"]["Value"])

allList = keywordList + companyList + ibanList
Transactions["Value"] = np.nan
for element in allList:
    Transactions["Value"] = np.where(Transactions["Transaction_description"].str.contains(element), element, Transactions["Value"])

# Merge the dataframes
TransactionsClassified = Transactions[["Transaction_description", "Value", "Amount"]].merge(Categorization[["Value", "MappingCode"]], on="Value")
```